# How to use $gt to check for date difference in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Am developing a nodejs app that will find users whose account are older than 4 minutes, normally I add 4 minutes to their expires date object during account verification`(user.expires: Date.now() + 240000)` of which is saved after. I wrote a `setInterval()` that will find the users after 1 minute. But the problem is that it brings out the users even before 4 minutes is reached. I don't know what am doing wrong.

```
router.get("/verification/user", isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
    User.findOne({ email: req.user.email }, function (err, user) {
        if (!user) {
            req.flash('error', 'There is no user with that email address');
            return res.redirect('/forgot');
        } else {

            user.verificationToken = token;
            user.expires = Date.now() + 240000;

            user.save(function (err, saved) {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(saved)
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

*setInterval function, I don't really know how to check if the account is older than 4 minutes*

```
function timing(){
    User.find({expires: {$gt: Date.now()}}, function(err, expired){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else if(expired.length > 0) {
            console.log('expired exist');
            console.log(expired);
        } else {
            console.log('none at the period');
        }
    })
}

setInterval(timing, 60000 );
```

**It keeps on bringing out users after every minute**

Comment: Your query is correct, there must be someting else going on. https://mongoplayground.net/p/96vpeXVCqQp

Comment: @Molda I have checked everything to see what am doing wrong, but I can't really see that.

Comment: @braza Am trying to find users account that is older than 4 minutes, but it logs out a new user after every one minute.

Comment: print the date inside Date.now() to see if not captured